# BST with recursive generator

Tags: python, recursion, generator, binary-search-tree, yield

I have a Tree class to which I added an in_order recursive method (seems to work well ).
Since I'd like to iterate over my Tree object, I thought I could just implement
the same logic under **next**, however I get an infinite generator loop.

Can you please let me know what am I missing?

```
class Tree:

    def __init__(self, left=None, right=None, data=None):
        self.data=data
        self.right=right
        self.left=left

    def in_order(self):
        if self.left is not None:
            yield from self.left.in_order()
        yield (self.data)
        if self.right is not None:
            yield from self.right.in_order()

    def __iter__(self):

        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.left is not None:
            yield from self.left.__next__()
        yield(self.data)
        if self.right is not None:
            yield from self.right.__next__()



t4 = Tree(data=5)
t6 = Tree(data=32)
t5 = Tree(data=10)
t1 = Tree(data=8, left=t4, right=t5)
t2 = Tree(data=35, left=t6)
t3 = Tree(left=t1, right=t2, data=20)


# Works well
gen = (t3.in_order())
for e in gen:
    print(e)

# Gets into an infinite loop
for e in t3:
    print(e)
```

Comment: try removing .__next__() from your code: eg `yield from self.left`

Comment: From the logic of `__next__` its content should be moved to `__iter__`. You don't need to define `__next__` at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An extended version of the comment:

```
class Tree:
    # can be simplified with @dataclass    
    def __init__(self, left=None, right=None, data=None):
        self.data=data
        self.right=right
        self.left=left

    def __iter__(self):
        if self.left is not None:
            yield from self.left
        yield (self.data)
        if self.right is not None:
            yield from self.right

     in_order = __iter__
```

Test:

```
t4 = Tree(data=5)
t6 = Tree(data=32)
t5 = Tree(data=10)
t1 = Tree(data=8, left=t4, right=t5)
t2 = Tree(data=35, left=t6)
t3 = Tree(left=t1, right=t2, data=20)
list(t3)
# returns [5, 8, 10, 20, 32, 35]
```

Comment: I thought that Iterator requires both __next__ and __iter__ implementations, because when running later for loop, is actually calling next(iterator_object) until exhaustion ().

Comment: @shermanv no, these are two different ways to create iterators. If the iterator has to be stateful, it's easier to use `__iter__`. For example, we get records from a database and then instantiate and yield objects created from those records. In stateless cases (e.g. generate random numbers), it is easier to generate results one by one using `__next__`

Answer (score 0):

```
class Tree:

    def __init__(self, left=None, right=None, data=None):
        self.data=data
        self.right=right
        self.left=left

    def in_order(self):
        if self.left is not None:
            yield from self.left.in_order()
        yield (self.data)
        if self.right is not None:
            yield from self.right.in_order()

    def __iter__(self):
        if self.left is not None:
            yield from self.left
        yield(self.data)
        if self.right is not None:
            yield from self.right



t4 = Tree(data=5)
t6 = Tree(data=32)
t5 = Tree(data=10)
t1 = Tree(data=8, left=t4, right=t5)
t2 = Tree(data=35, left=t6)
t3 = Tree(left=t1, right=t2, data=20)


# Works well
gen = (t3.in_order())
for e in gen:
    print(e)

# Works well
for e in t3:
    print(e)
```

You are doing an infinite recursion when using `yield` with `__next__`, if you remove it the problem is solved

[test online](https://repl.it/repls/IdleHeavenlyMatter)